# How to handle multiple piece of data from server

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, nsstream

I know my question is confusing. Let me clarify it here:

1. I'm using NSStreamdelegate in ios as the socket handler, and node.js as server.
2. There would be multiple socket.write(data) call between a very little time interval.
3. So my question here is since NSStreamdelegate handle data by "one-by-one" bytes, what if two piece of data reach exactly right the same time. Would they be mixed with each other? Or would the NSSstreamdelegate recognize them as in the same stream?

Do I need a separator in my data that I write on server? However, since the data sent could be large, it is difficult to check the separator on client side.